# Looping over the messages in IBM MQ server

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have few hundreds of messages in my MQ server(using MQ .NET).

I am trying to read those one by one, however i am having issue in looping thro' that. I don't have any count/length property that i can use in this regard.

mqQueue  - MQQueue
mqQMgr - MQ QueueManager

```
   mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
   mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts); 
   string readMessage = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
```

How can i loop thro' all the messages in the queue and if there is no message i want exit out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line i was looking for, moving the cursor to the next message, so that i can read the next message.

> mGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;

MQGetMessageOptions:

```
queue.Get(message);
Console.WriteLine("Message " + i + " got = " + message.ReadString(message.MessageLength));
mGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
```

Comment: This is not clear and I don't think it resolves the issue. `mGetMsgOpts` is never passed to `queue.Get` method

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the sample programs that installed with the WMQ code.  By default, these will live in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ 7.5\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\` and the one I think you want is `SimpleGet.cs`.

The problem you are having is that you are opening the queue repeatedly.  That resets the rowse pointer to the head of the queue eac time.  The sample program shows how to open the queue once, then loop through messages until reaching a certain number or until the queue is empty, whichever comes first.

```
            // create connection
            Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            // accessing queue
            Console.Write("Accessing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            // getting messages continuously
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
            {
                // creating a message object
                message = new MQMessage();

                try
                {
                    queue.Get(message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message " + i + " got = " + message.ReadString(message.MessageLength));
                    message.ClearMessage();
                }
                catch (MQException mqe)
                {
                    if (mqe.ReasonCode == 2033)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No message available");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("MQException caught: {0} - {1}", mqe.ReasonCode, mqe.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The IBM install media with the code samples is downloadable as [SupportPac MC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMC75).  If for some reason you need a back-level client, they are available from the SupportPacs [main page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  However, keep in mind that there has been a lot of engineering in the later releases and you are MUCH better off with the latest version.  Any version of MQ client can work with any version of QMgr, but obviously the functionality you get is either that only on the client side (such as the client.ini file) or on the server side, whatever that level of QMgr gives you.  In other words, using a V7.5 client with a v7.0 QMgr works fine, but it doesn't give you CHLAUTH rules because the v7.0 QMgr doesn't have those.

Comment: Thanks, how is the value for numberOfMsgs being calculated?

Comment: It is passed in from the command line.  Do you have the sample code?  Do you need a link to the download?

Comment: I need to get all the messages one by one, something like i will write a method, GetAllMessages() and have those messages read one by one with their message id, share the link/quick pseudo code please.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get the .Net DLL installed and registered without installing the vendor media so I'm very surprised you don't already have the samples.  However, I've posted a link to the official installation package.  The WMQ client is a free download, although I believe that you have to register for the download.

Comment: how is the value for numberOfMsgs: queue.CurrentDepth